# get the index of the min size list in an arrayList using java stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of Integer List, like list1=(1,2,3) and list2 = (0,1).

my list of lists contains list1 and list2. It could contains more but for the example i took only two lists.

The question is to get the index of the list with minimum size using java stream.

Here is my program and it work using only the for loop method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {

     public static void main( String[] args ) {


         ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
         list1.add(1);list1.add(2);list1.add(3);

         ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
         list2.add(0);list2.add(1);

         ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOLists = new ArrayList<>();
         listOLists.add(list1);
         listOLists.add(list2);
         printTheIndexOfTheListWithTheMinSize(listOLists);
     }

    private static void printTheIndexOfTheListWithTheMinSize( ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOLists ) {
        int minSize  = listOLists.get(0).size();
        int minIndex = 0;
        int i=0;
        for ( ArrayList<Integer> list:  listOLists ) {

            if (list.size()<minSize)
            {
                minSize = list.size();
                minIndex=i;
            }
            i++;

        }
        System.out.println(minIndex);
    }
}
```

Could you please give me a hint how to do that using Java stream API.

Note that i'm calling this method many times in a heavy calcul, so  the awnser should take that in consideration.

Comment: After `list2` is declared and initialized no elements are added to it. In the next line `0` and `1` are added to `list1`. A typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really elegant, because it requires boxing and unboxing, but...

```
Optional<Integer> minIndex = 
    IntStream.range(0, list.size())
             .boxed()
             .min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> list.get(i).size()));
```

Comment: This boxing overhead is far less overhead than the `indexOf` operations of other answers…

Comment: Alternatively, without boxing `IntStream.range(0, list.size()) .reduce((a, b) -> list.get(a).size() <= list.get(b).size()? a: b)`

Answer (score 3):

One way to possibly do that would be using `indexOf` and `Collections.min` with a `comparator` as:

```
int minIndex = listOLists.indexOf(Collections.min(listOLists, 
                                   Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Stay away from solutions using `indexOf`. While they may allow to write rather short code, this `indexOf` operation bears a content-based linear search operation, invoking `equals` on the list elements until a match is found.

While it might look like a trivial thing, as all sub-lists differ in size, except for the matching element, most of Java 8’s `List` implementations do not use the size to short-cut the comparison.

To illustrate the issue,

use the following helper class

```
class Counter {
  int count;
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    count++;
    return super.equals(obj);
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "equals invoked "+count+" times";
  }
}
```

and

```
Counter c = new Counter();
List<List<Counter>> list = Arrays.asList(
  new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, c)),
  new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(15, c)),
  new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(7, c)),
  new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, c))
  );

Comparator<List<?>> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(List::size);

System.out.println("using IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()\r\n" + 
  "               .min(Comparator.comparing(list::get, cmp))");
int minIndex = 
  IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
           .min(Comparator.comparing(list::get, cmp)).orElse(-1);
System.out.println("result "+minIndex+", "+c);
c.count = 0;

System.out.println("\nusing list.indexOf(Collections.min(list, cmp))");
minIndex = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list, cmp));
System.out.println("result "+minIndex+", "+c);
c.count = 0;

System.out.println("\nusing list.indexOf(list.stream().min(cmp).get())");
minIndex = list.indexOf(list.stream().min(cmp).get());
System.out.println("result "+minIndex+", "+c);
```

it will print

```
using IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
               .min(Comparator.comparing(list::get, cmp))
result 2, equals invoked 0 times

using list.indexOf(Collections.min(list, cmp))
result 2, equals invoked 14 times

using list.indexOf(list.stream().min(cmp).get())
result 2, equals invoked 14 times
```

in Java 8, showing that calling `equals` on any contained element is an unnecessary operation (see the first variant, derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525342/2711488)), but performed multiple times for the other variants. Now imagine what happens if we use larger lists and/or a larger number of lists and have an element type with a rather expensive equality test.

Note that for `ArrayList`, this has been solved in JDK 11, but there are still list implementations left, like the ones returned by `Collections.nCopies` or `Arrays.asList`, which do not short circuit, so it’s generally preferable not to do an entirely obsolete content based linear search operation.

Comment: Nice answer as always. The `equals` implementation was added only in JDK11 to the ArrayList class. But I don't quite understand the shortcircuiting part. Wouldn't the `equals` in the `AbstractList` (or in other words equals of ArrayList pre Java 11) also shortcirucit?

Comment: I think I got it. They have a different/special method (`equalsArrayList`) when the other object is an ArrayList and they will not even do the traversal of the two lists if the sizes are unequal. Am I right?

Comment: @user7 exactly, the difference lies in the size check. `AbstractList.equals` does not check the size; since it doesn’t know the actual implementation logic, determining the size could be an expensive operation, so it doesn’t use it. So all list implementations with a cheap size operation (almost all of them) should insert such a check, as a different size precludes equality.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
int index = listOLists.indexOf(listOLists.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
                .orElseGet(ArrayList::new));
```

or if you want to avoid the creation of an `ArrayList` when the source is empty then you could do:

```
int index = listOLists.isEmpty() ? -1 : listOLists.indexOf(listOLists.stream()
                  .min(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)).get());
```

Comment: When passed an empty list, this will return -1 which is better than the OP's current code which will fail with a NPE

Comment: is this solution better than the for loop way in question of performance

Comment: @zakzak You need to measure it (Note: Streams have some overhead)

Comment: @zakzak it’s likely much worse than the loop equivalent, as this solution (exactly like [the accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525493/2711488)) first searches for the minimum element, but then performs an additional expensive linear search for its index via `indexOf` which involves comparing all elements of the list (and you would be surprised, how many `List` implementations do not short-cut when the size differs or when compared with itself). That content comparison is orders of magnitude more expensive than comparing list by their size.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that creates index/size arrays and finds the min by size:

```
IntStream.range(0, listOLists.size())
         .mapToObj(i -> new int[] { i, listOLists.get(i).size() })
         .min(Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]))
         .map(arr -> arr[0])
         .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

This will print the index of min-sized list in `listOLists`